# Flexslider2 example: Same code, different outcomes (Locally and jsfiddle)

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, flexslider

I have implemented Flexslider2 both locally and on a jsfiddle. Each uses the exact same code. However when view my page locally on (Firefox, Chrome and IE9) the Flexslide only resizes the images width.

The jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/T64Gp/3/, produces the desired outcome where the image's aspect ratio is maintained

My local code (HTML) is as follows. There are no styles outside of the flexslider.css and no additional javascript outside of jQuery and flexslider.js.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css">   
    </head>
    <body>        
    <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li>
                <img src="1.jpg" alt="1" title="1">
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="2.jpg" alt="2" title="2">
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="3.jpg" alt="3" title="3">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="flexslider.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any insight on why this might be happening would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is your `</html>`? Looks like the browser will be entering quirks mode

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but the fiddle that you provided doesn't seem the maintain the aspect ratio. For me, the height of the picture stays the same but the width changes on window resizing.

Comment: @basilikum Interesting it looks like somehow a width and height attribute was added to each image in the slideshow. That was not the case when I created the fiddle and is not the case on my local site. I've hopefully corrected the fiddle.

Comment: By adding `height: auto;` to `.flexslider .slides img` this fixes the issue for me but I do not think this was intended and still do not understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions you could try:

Your code above and the jsFiddle are using different versions of jQuery. [The flexslider example page](http://flexslider.woothemes.com) uses jQuery 1.9.1 so maybe it's best to stick with this for now

The most likely cause though is that you should initialise flexslider with

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(window).load(function() {
$('.flexslider').flexslider();
});
</script>
```

This will ensure that the page content is loaded before flexslider initialises.

Good luck!